# DBT API, or any Idea to get the Lineage from the DBT Explorer

Tags: python, dbt

We want to retrieve the linage from DBT Explorer, I was not able find any API from DBT which will give us as a response which has json of the lineage or lineage itself.

To brief it.

We want to access this link :  https://cloud.getdbt.com/explore/8888/projects/8888/lineage/?select=10%2Bmodel.xxxx.yyyyy

it has suppose a lineage like this when accessed from browser :
[image]

We want get this lineage snap or get info from any api and create a lineage like this and store it some place like PBI report or any storage.

can some one suggest any tools or anything using python we can use to do this

Answer (score 0):

### An easy way

dbt run will generate a file `target/manifest.json` which has the information of dependency. Here comes a sample snippet.

```
"depends_on": {
    "macros": [
        "macro.F1.source"
    ],
    "nodes": [
        "source.F1.f1_dataset.status"
    ]
}
```

So we can construct the whole lineage based on this information.

There is one drawback for this approach though. It can not realtime after just change a model. As it has to run to generate to manifest.

### A better way

A more realtime approach will be parse those model files on the fly. Though very challenge due to the Jinja could be arbitrary nested and complex.